# What is a utility biller?

Tags: billing, utility

I came across [this](https://www.sc.com/in/credit-cards/super-value-titanium.html) credit card which offers 5% cashback on utility billers like electricity, gas, water and more and 0.5% on any category which does not get the 5% cashback.
However, I will take that card only if it offers 5% cashback on insurance biller as well.
I do not understand whether an insurance biller is a utility biller.
Basically I want to know the exhaustive list of what else can come under utility biller (besides electricity, gas and water).

Answer (score 4):

Insurance company doesn't, to the best of my knowledge, provide any utility services to your household. Why would you think they would fit the "utility" category?

They don't. Electricity, gas and water *is* the exhaustive list. In many cases TV/internet/cable/phone is also considered utility, check with your credit card issuer, but it is not always.

Comment: Its best to check with Card Provider. List varies. Even insurance, they may allow one company but not the other.

Comment: It actually may depend more on the merchant services provider to the biller than the consumer card provider...

Comment: "Electricity, gas and water _is_ the exhaustive list." Might sewage also be included where applicable? We are charged monthly for sewage based on the water usage of the household: those with garden sprinkler systems usually have a separate water meter for "unsewered" water on which the sewage district does not levy a charge.

Comment: +1 for - check with your credit card issuer. No matter what your experience, a difference card might handle this differently. "Check with your credit card issuer" is right for most quirky things that are not regulated.

Comment: @Dilip isn't it part of the water bill?

Comment: No, the Sanitary District is a local government entity and bills separately from the water company (though the bill amount is determined by water usage, which information the District gets from the water company).